# Variable scope for nested functions in python

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have a demo example:

```
def outer(func):

    def inner(foo):   
        arg_inner=some_value     
        func(arg_inner,foo)     

    return inner

 def third_party(arg1,arg2):
     #do something

     final = outer(third_party)
     final(3)
```

I wonder how comes the inner function knows the value of `func` while being called. How the scope of inner function and outer are connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler connects them.

When compiling `outer` and `inner`, the `func` name in `outer` is marked as a closure, and a free variable in `inner`. On execution, the interpreter then knows to attach a reference to the `func` name from `outer` to the `inner` function object as a closure cell.

You can see the result in the disassembly of the bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(outer)
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (func)
              3 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object inner at 0x1079a5ab0, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              9 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (inner)

  4          15 LOAD_FAST                1 (inner)
             18 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> inner = outer(lambda a, b: None)
>>> dis.dis(inner)
  3           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (func)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (arg_inner)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 POP_TOP             
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `LOAD_CLOSURE` wraps the `func` name in a closure for `inner` to use; `MAKE_CLOSURE` builds a function object (from the byte code object loaded with `LOAD_CONST`) with attached closure cells as a tuple. In `inner`, the `LOAD_DEREF` opcode loads the value from the `func` closure.

The closure can be found back on the resulting `inner` function object:

```
>>> inner.func_closure
(<cell at 0x107a25a28: function object at 0x107a28b18>,)
>>> inner.func_code.co_freevars
('func',)
>>> inner.func_closure[0].cell_contents
<function <lambda> at 0x107a28b18>
```

so the `inner` function object carries the closure with it for later dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

look at http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding.It contains explanations about scops.